# Why is my Android background color not visible?

Tags: android, android-view

I'm trying to figure out one simple thing: how to set a background color in Android view. Here is the code in an Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View v = new  View(this);

    setContentView(v);
    v.setBackgroundColor(23423425);
}
```

and all I get is black screen.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The integer you set is easier represented as a hex value.  The hex values are `0xAARRGGBB`.

- A - represents the Alpha value which is how transparent the color is.  A value of `FF` means it's not transparent at all.  A value of `00` means the color won't be shown at all and everything behind it will be visible.
- R - Red value; self-explanatory
- G - Green value; self-explanatory
- B - Blue value; self-explanatory

What you entered in hex is `0x016569C1` which has an Alpha values of 1 (barely visible).  Put, `0xFFFF0000` and you'll have a red background.

Comment: you're right. it's absolutely stupid mistake. i've just entered a random integer :)

Answer (score 3):

You are passing in the color incorrectly. DeeV got to it before me but you need to use a hex value.

Here is a link that lists all combinations for easy access.

[Colors for Android](http://www.ceveni.com/2009/08/set-rgb-color-codes-for-android-and-rgb.html)

You can also set in the XML by using

```
android:background = "#FF00000000"
```

Which would be black.

Comment: Actually, in that case it would be an invisible black.  If there was anything behind the view, it would show up.  `#FF000000` would be black and block out everything behind it.

Answer (score 2):

Common way to represent color in ARGB(sometimes RGBA but it is just a naming) model is hexadecimal. No one uses decimal numeral system to represent color digitally.

let's set yellow color to button's text: `button.setTextColor(0xFFFFFF00);`. Now We set yellow to out button's text.

ARGB consists of 4 cannel. each with 8-bit. first channel is alfa - 0x`FF`FFFFFF; alfa is opacity level(in this case we have max value of it). second is red - 0xFF`FF`FF00, and so on; green and blue respectively.

The easiest way to create color in ARGB color model with decimal numeral system is to use `Color` class.

`Color` class has all basic static functions and fields. 
In your case you can use static function `Color.rgb(int red, int, green, int blue)` where `red, green, blue` must be in the range of 0 to 255. Alfa bits by default is set to max - 255 or in hex - 0xff.

Now you know how to represent color in hexadecimal numeric system it will be very easy to create color in xml resource file.